# AudioTrack in foreground Service not getting enough CPU time

Tags: java, android, android-service, audiotrack

I have an app that is streaming processed audio bytes to an AudioTrack. The AudioTrack's buffer size is set to 4K and is being fed data in 2K chunks. It's running in a Thread in a Service, that is running via bindService() and startService() when it's associated Activity is in the foreground.

When the Activity pauses, by pressing the home button for example, the Service has startForeground() called on it, with the Notification appearing. The problem is the audio is occasionally garbled or distorted when in the startForeground() state, but is perfectly fine when the associated Activity is in the foreground and running. It should be noted that the AudioTrack is not reporting any buffer underflows when the audio is distorting.

I can fix this by raising the AudioTrack's buffer to 32K, but this is not ideal for my app.

Is there any solution for this? I've tried calling

```
Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
```

in the run() method of my Runnable, but it doesn't help.